# changing only numerical data in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have DafaFrame:

```
  text  value_1  value_2
0  egg        2        1
1  ham        4        2
2  bla        4        3
```

I would like to chance only number by multiplying each value by 2. How to omit the text column?
instead of

```
     text  value_1  value_2
0  eggegg        4        2
1  hamham        8        4
2  blabla        8        6
```

I woult like to get:

```
 text  value_1  value_2
0  egg        4        2
1  ham        8        4
2  bla        8        6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select columns a specific dtype with select_dtype:

```
In [11]: df.select_dtypes(include=['int64'])
Out[11]:
   value_1  value_2
0        2        1
1        4        2
2        4        3

In [12]: df.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'floating'])
Out[12]:
   value_1  value_2
0        2        1
1        4        2
2        4        3
```

This means you can update df as follows:

```
In [21]: s = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64']) * 2

In [22]: df[s.columns] = s

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
  text  value_1  value_2
0  egg        4        2
1  ham        8        4
2  bla        8        6
```

Comment: Note: this is actually less efficient than just updating the int columns, but I thought work mentioning.

Comment: I wasn't aware of 'select_dtypes`. Thanks this is useful

Comment: @JBradley I was actually hoping there was a way to `select_dtypes` to get the boolean for the columns (to more generically do the `df.dtypes == np.int64` in your answer).

Answer (score 2):

you can select the columns by dtype, and return only the columns with numeric types before multiplying:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'food': ['eggs','eggs','ham','ham'],'co1':[20,19,20,21,],
  'col2': [10,10,20,20]})
```

updated to return all columns:

```
df.update(df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.int64] *2)
```

returns:

```
    co1 col2 food
0   40  20  eggs
1   38  20  eggs
2   40  40  ham
3   42  40  ham
```